# GDB misses to display const qualifier?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, constants, pointer-to-array

Give the following source (`main.c`):

```
void foo(const char (*pa)[4])
{
}

int main(void)
{
  const char a[4] = "bar";

  foo(&a);
}
```

... compiled with GCC (gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2) and run under GDB (GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1) ...

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004c8: file main.c, line 7.
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4004be: file main.c, line 3.
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:7
7     const char a[4] = "bar";
(gdb) p &a
$1 = (const char (*)[4]) 0x7fffffffe1a0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, foo (pa=0x7fffffffe1a0) at main.c:3
3   }
(gdb) p pa
$2 = (char (*)[4]) 0x7fffffffe1a0
```

... why does GDB show me `(char (*)[4])` instead of `(const char (*)[4])` as type for `foo()`'s parameter `pa`? What happened to the `const` qualifier? Or am I missing something essential? :-S

---

**Update**:

`pa` behaves as expected. If for example doing

```
   char (*t)[4] = pa;
```

inside `foo()` the compiler complains:

```
 warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Whereas doing

```
   const char (*t)[4] = pa;
```

works fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding to make `a` `static`? Or to do something with passed par into foo function?

Comment: @LPs What does that have to do with the declaration of `pa`?

Comment: @Barmar I was guessing about optimizer. Probably I failed... ;)

Comment: This is probably a bug fixed since (GDB 7.7.1 release) as I can't reproduce it using GDB 7.11.

Comment: Probably a gdb bug (gdb 7.10.1 doesn't seem to have it).

Comment: The `const` qualifier for `pa` simply isn't there in the DWARF info. Reproduced using gcc 4.8.4 and 4.9.2 (and gdb 7.7.1 and 7.11.1) on Ubuntu and Debian.